# How to efficiently differentiate between tap and swipe in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, swipe

It's the first time I'm trying to make a mobile game with touch controls in Unity. I basically got it working. But there's a problem, how do you make it clear that a swipe isn't a tap?

How my code, that I partially found on tutorials, works is that, to register a tap I look if the user has his touch stationary for a minimum amount of time, 0.05 seconds in this case. And for the swipe, I look if the user's touch moves around by a minimum distance.

The problem is, quite often the start of a swipe is registered as a tap since the user doesn't move his finger for 0.05 seconds. I could simply make the minimum stationary time to register a tap higher, but that would mean that there would be way more delay in the game between the moment the user taps the screen and the action gets executed...

Is there a perfect solution to my problem? In the mobile game Rayman Adventures the tap makes the player jump and swipe changes his directions and it works quite smoothly, only on very few occasions does the player jump when you try to change directions. I have no idea how they got it working.

Here's my code:

```cs
    public static event Action<SwipeData> OnSwipe = delegate { };
    public static event Action OnTap = delegate { };

    [Header("Swipe parameters")]
    [SerializeField]
    bool m_DetectSwipeOnlyAfterRelease;
    [SerializeField]
    float m_MinDistanceForSwipe;

    [Header("Tap parameters")]
    [SerializeField]
    float m_TapTimeMinThreshold;

    private Vector2 m_FingerDownPosition;
    private Vector2 m_FingerUpPosition;

    private float m_TouchTime;
    private bool m_StationaryTouch;
    private bool m_TapRegistered;
    private bool m_SwipeRegistered;

    void Start() {
        m_TapRegistered = true;
        m_SwipeRegistered = true;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                m_FingerUpPosition = touch.position;
                m_FingerDownPosition = touch.position;
                m_TouchTime = Time.time;
                m_StationaryTouch = true;
                m_TapRegistered = false;
                m_SwipeRegistered = false;
            }
            
            if(!m_SwipeRegistered && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
                m_StationaryTouch = false;
                m_FingerDownPosition = touch.position;
                SwipeDirection swipeDirection = DetectSwipe();
                // If a swipe was registered
                if (!swipeDirection.Equals(SwipeDirection.NONE)) {
                    // And it was horizontal, we reset the swipe detection
                    if (swipeDirection.Equals(SwipeDirection.LEFT) || swipeDirection.Equals(SwipeDirection.RIGHT))
                        m_FingerUpPosition = touch.position;
                    else
                        m_SwipeRegistered = true;
                }
            }

            // If the touch was stationary for the min threshold amount of time we register it as a tap
            if (m_StationaryTouch && !m_TapRegistered && Time.time - m_TouchTime > m_TapTimeMinThreshold) {
                m_TapRegistered = true;
                OnTap();
            }
            
            if (!m_SwipeRegistered && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && !m_TapRegistered) {
                m_FingerDownPosition = touch.position;
                DetectSwipe();
            }
        }
    }

    private SwipeDirection DetectSwipe() {
        if (SwipeDistanceCheckMet()) {
            SwipeDirection direction;
            if (IsVerticalSwipe()) {
                direction = m_FingerDownPosition.y - m_FingerUpPosition.y > 0 ? SwipeDirection.UP : SwipeDirection.DOWN;
                SendSwipe(direction);
            }
            else {
                direction = m_FingerDownPosition.x - m_FingerUpPosition.x > 0 ? SwipeDirection.RIGHT : SwipeDirection.LEFT;
                SendSwipe(direction);
            }
            m_FingerUpPosition = m_FingerDownPosition;
            return direction;
        }
        return SwipeDirection.NONE;
    }

    private bool IsVerticalSwipe() {
        return VerticalMovementDistance() > HorizontalMovementDistance();
    }

    private bool SwipeDistanceCheckMet() {
        return VerticalMovementDistance() > m_MinDistanceForSwipe || HorizontalMovementDistance() > m_MinDistanceForSwipe;
    }

    private float VerticalMovementDistance() {
        return Mathf.Abs(m_FingerDownPosition.y - m_FingerUpPosition.y);
    }

    private float HorizontalMovementDistance() {
        return Mathf.Abs(m_FingerDownPosition.x - m_FingerUpPosition.x);
    }

    private void SendSwipe(SwipeDirection direction) {
        SwipeData swipeData = new SwipeData()
        {
            Direction = direction,
            StartPosition = m_FingerDownPosition,
            EndPosition = m_FingerUpPosition
        };
        OnSwipe(swipeData);
    }
```

Comment: A "swipe" will likely have a very long distance between start and end. `MOVE` is not guaranteed to be sufficient, as it will trigger after as little as 1 pixel. A "tap," meanwhile, will generally have very low *time* between start and end (which distinguishes it from "tap-and-hold" or "long press").

Comment: I agree, but if I use the end event on the touch phase it's too much delay. When you play a game you want the character to jump (for example) right away when you touch the screen. You don't want it to jump only when you remove your finger...

Comment: Welcome to the eternal problem of why touchscreens are terrible. You're just going to have to deal with some amount of delay. Alternatively, buy an asset.